# rurequire_once file not found if called from within a folder

Tags: php

I have a website built through PHP using PDO. In my `init.php` file I use the `spl_autoload_register` method and then I `require_once` a `sanitize.php` file to sanitize data. When I `require` the `core/init.php` file from the root folder, it all works fine, but if I make a folder inside of root, no matter what it is called, and I require `../core/init.php` then it throws this error:

```
[03-Apr-2014 22:10:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require_once(functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project1/login/core/init.php on line 29
```

This is the `init.php` file:

```
// Autoload classes
function autoload($class) {
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');

// Include functions
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

File Structure:

```
root
   core
     init.php
   classes
     ... all classes
   css
   functions
     sanitize.php
   processes
     login.inc.php
   js
     script.js
   index.php
```

Inside the script file, I am calling the `login.inc.php` file. If the `login.inc.php` file is outside of the `processes` folder, it works fine and there are no errors, if it is inside the `processes` folder, it throws that error.

Comment: There should be no such file like `sanitize.php` on a website built through PHP using PDO. 

Most likely this file is written based on some delusion, already many times discussed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the docroot variable:

```
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once($doc_root . "/functions/sanitize.php");
```

Comment: Would you care to define "messes up"?

Comment: Then it says it cannot find the classes that are loaded first

Comment: Well yeah, you will have to use the docroot var for ALL includes and requires, not just `sanitize.php`.

Comment: For example, if you are including a class from within `sanitize.php`, you will need `include($doc_root . "/classes/class.php);`...

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions/sanitize.php';
```

Comment: What do you mean by the `__DIR__` ?

Comment: It's a predefined constant in PHP.

Comment: What file are you calling it from, and give me the directory layout.

Comment: @user3241507 it's just a magic chant used by php users every time they encounter a file not found error